# How can i get a data set having only Audio and Video packets?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Where can I find data set consisting of only audio and video traffic?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78440/where-can-i-find-data-set-consisting-of-only-audio-and-video-traffic)

Anybody with any advice? Thanks.

Comment: If you had enough reputation, you could ask on [chat].

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [help center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions for resources are explicitly off-topic here:

> ### Off-Topic
>
> **If your question is about**
>
> - ...
> - product or resource recommendations;
> - ...
>
> **then this is NOT the place to ask.**

Such questions attract spam and opinions which the community has decided they don't want here.

Comment: first, not allowed on `Network Engg`, instead recommended `Network Exchange Meta`. now, not even allowed here.

Comment: On Meta, you can only ask questions about the main site, e.g. why your main question was closed. That I answered.